# How to re-occupy status bar space after leaving it transparent

Tags: android, android-layout

I using `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>` in my AppTheme for the `StatusBar`, it works, but now the `Toolbar` starts at same point of the `StatusBar` and no after it (as it was before).

With the `Statusbar` transparent it stays like this:
[image]

How to re-ocuppy this space for differents `StatusBar`'s (for multiple phones)?

Comment: `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

Comment: In `AndroidManifest`, right?

Comment: I try this and don't work (in the AndroidManifest and in Activity).